# Displaying escaped HTML in angular

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a simplified way to display escaped html code in the browser. I.e. this is for a "quick start / lib demo" page.

So I want to display this line as it is (without angular intercepting and calling the component):

```
<wd-input [label]="'this is a label'"></wd-input>
```

I tried a something like:

```
{{ '<wd-input [label]="'this is a label'"></wd-input>' }}
```

But it didn't work, Angular still compiled and rendered it.

Edit: to provide more context, this is what I'm going to have to do unless we find a better way (i.e. manually escaping the html directly in the template):

```
&lt;wd-input [label]="'this is a label'"&gt;&lt;/wd-input;
```

Comment: If showing that text in a `div` element is an option, you can bind the `innerText` property, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjw1vz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try storing the html string in a variable and presenting that on the page.

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `    
<div> {{htmlString }}</div>
`
})

export class AppComponent  {

htmlString = `<wd-input [label]="'this is a label'"></wd-input>`;
  constructor() {}  
}
```

**UPDATE**
I created a wrapper component that takes the first element and stores it as a string then presents it using ng-content.  Take a look.  You can use this https://stackblitz.com/edit/quick-html-wrapper

Comment: Right, so that works but it would look pretty crappy with a ton of html inside my class. I guess I'm trying to have angular skip template parsing somehow for just a portion of my page...

Comment: You could create a class/service full of html strings and import them in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get around escaping quotes if you want to keep HTML within the template. Maybe the closest solution possible:

```
<span [innerText]="'<wd-input [label]=&quot;\'this is a label\'&quot;></wd-input>'"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ### **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-and-code-uncompiled)

---

> ### 2 approaches i'm doing in here
>
> **1. To escape double curly braces `{{}}` I've used `DomSanitizer`to`bypassSecurityTrustHtml` to show raw code and Replaced `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`**
>
> **2. I used `textarea readonly` and some `CSS` styling to show raw html content.**

**Your `component.ts` can be something like below:~**

```
import { Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  templatehtml: string;
  html: SafeHtml;
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {

    this.templatehtml = `
      import { Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
      import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
      import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

      @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '&lt;span&gt;{{name}}&lt;/span&gt;'
      })

      export class AppComponent {
        name = "Angular";
      }  
    `;


    this.html = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.templatehtml);
  }
}
```

**Your `component.html` can be something like below:~**

```
<div class="container">
  <b>Your raw component looks something like</b> 
  <pre [innerHtml]="html"></pre>

  <b>Your raw html looks something like</b> 
  <textarea readonly>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <wd-input [label]="'this is a label'"></wd-input>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
          Go somewhere
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </textarea>

  <b>This is the rendered html</b> 
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
        Go somewhere
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**and text area `CSS` like**

```
textarea {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none; /*remove the resize handle on the bottom right*/
}
```

**Hope this is helpful!**