# Display for loop in angular

Tags: angular

I'm finding it hard to display code in angular

Input

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    read str[i];
    }
```

Output

```
for(int i=0;i
```

Greater than or less than symbol breaks the line. If space is given between i and < symbol i.e, i <  0 instead of i<0, then it is printed correctly. I tried using code and pre tags. Still getting the same bug. I want to display the code as such without adding space, any libraries available for this?

Comment: AFAIK the generally accepted workaround is to use `&lt` and `&gt` for `<` and `>` symbols respectively. Try: `for(int i=0;i&lt;n;i++)`

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56082580/displaying-escaped-html-in-angular/56082668). Possibly a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the `{` and the `}` Angular wait to a `{{`

You can try enclosed by `{{'` and `'}}`

```
<pre>
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{{'{'}}
    read str[i];
{{'}'}}
</pre>
```

Another way is

```
<pre>
{{'for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    read str[i];
}
'}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASCII characters in `HTML`in this way `&#X;`.

- `&#60;` is for <
- `&#62;` is for >
- `&#123;` is for {
- `&#125;` is for }
- `&#123;` is for {
- `&nbsp;` if for white space

Complete list [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_ascii_codes.htm)

Try this:

```html
<div >
    <p>
     for(int i=0;i&#60;n;i++) <br>
     &#123; <br>
     read str[i]; <br> 
     &#125;<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

And with the extra spaces:

```html
<div >
    <p>
     for(int i=0;i&#60;n;i++) <br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#123; <br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;read str[i]; <br> 
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#125;<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

You can see a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-of1cvf?file=src/app/app.component.html)