# Render HTML special characters in angular 13

Tags: angular

I use Angular v13.

When i display text contains HTML special characters, the text shows without applying those special characters :

It shows `Hello &lt;b&gt;world&lt;/b&gt;`  instead of `Hello <b>world</b>`

My code :

```js
export class FormDepartementComponent implements OnInit {
     readonly myText: string = 'Hello &lt;b&gt;world&lt;/b&gt;';
}
```

```html
<div>{{ myText }}</div>
```

I search for a global solution and without allowing HTML tags to be rendred.

**Many thanks for any help**

Comment: How do you display this text? Show your code please.

Comment: @Rafael, I put my Code

Comment: Check this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56082580/displaying-escaped-html-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249234/2564406) does what you're looking for.

Essentialy you use this method (you can make a pipe of it) to desanitize html from your variable.

```js
htmlDecode(input: string): string {
 var e = document.createElement('div');
 e.innerHTML = input;
 return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the innerHTML property binding

`<div [innerHtml]="myText" ></div>`